# Possible to have an app self delete/destruct/stop working after set time?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, mobile-application, mobile-phones

I was wondering if there's a way to add a line in maybe manifest that works something like
IF InstallTime>=24 hours
Then delete app/ display app unavailable activity

So I can show a client a sample apk before buying then have it automatically stop working after a set time. So I have the apk download through adb, let them try it out while we discuss the product, then when we're done just in case have it stop working so I wouldn't have to worry to much about taking their device and deleting it manually.

Answer (score 2):

```
I think in your Java class you can use this to check app install time.


try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

    Date installTime = new Date( packageInfo.firstInstallTime );
    Log.d("hi", "Installed: " + installTime.toString());

    Date updateTime = new Date( packageInfo.lastUpdateTime );
    Log.d("hi", "Updated: " + updateTime.toString());
}
catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

The packageInfo.firstInstallTime gives you the time as October 18, 2015 00:00:00 UTC)
You can check that if it is more than 24 hours then you can kill by using this android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()) in onDestroy or simply you can use finish()
```

Comment: I'm interesed, could you give a more concrete example? Where should go this bunch of code in the Application class?

Comment: In the MAinActivity where you begin your 1st activity or service

Comment: Cool snippet, It'll go to my favorites toolbox :D. I used the SharedPreferences for this kind of stuff.